# unable to load certificate 3070604992:error:0906D066:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line:pem_lib.c:809:

Tags: openssl, x509certificate

Hello im trying to get the certificate from [www.aws.amazon.com/](http://www.aws.amazon.com/) for educational purposes only and while im loading my certificate int the c1.pem:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

im using this command on my VM `openssl x509 -in c1.pem -noout -modulus` but i only get this error: `unable to load certificate 3070604992:error:0906D066:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line:pem_lib.c:809:`. Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: The data you've posted (which I presume was copy&pasted) is valid (although it's a cert for Amazon's _CA_ not for the website), so there must be something different in your file, such as invisible character(s). If on Unix, use `od -c c1.pem` or `cat -vET c1.pem` or `sed -n l c1.pem` (that's lower-ell) to see _exactly_ what is in the file. If on Windows, unless you have WSL or something else Unixy like cygwin or git4win installed, powershell's `format-hex c1.pem` comes fairly close. But this is not programming or development :-(

Comment: should be something with the domain name because i tried Google CA, did the same steps and worked perfectly

Comment: It cannot be the 'domain name', or even the cert. It can only be the file. Whatever you did the second time was in fact not the same, and was correct, so it is probably impossible to reconstruct what was wrong the first time.